# Add map by react native

Tags: android, google-maps, github, npm, react-native

I need to add map to my application as google maps
when I choose place from input or what ever , to show maps or filter component on maps due to this choice ,
what I exactly need is how to start maps on my app by react native .
I try to install this `npm install react-native-maps --save`
using this plugin 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps

but it gives me errors

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      region: this.getInitialState()
    };
  }

  getInitialState() {

  return {
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
  };
}

onRegionChange(region) {
  this.setState({ region });
}

render() {
  return (
   /*   <View><Text>hi</Text></View> />*/
 <MapView style={styles.map}
      region={this.state.region}
      onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
    />

  );
}
}
```

Display blank page and gives me warning, ''
and I tried a lot of maps but I get lost.
So please help how can I start?!

Comment: You could poke around in the example code.  https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/tree/master/example

Comment: Oh that error makes sense... See how you set the region to an empty string? And you see what the getInitialState() method returns? You can initialize region by calling that method

Comment: @cricket_007 
 
it gives me warning and also display nothing, `getInitialState was defined on app. a plain JavaScrpit class. This is only supported for classes created using react.creatclass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?`

Answer (score 2):

Try initializing the region with your initialization method

```
this.state = {
  region: this.getInitialState()
};
```

Or maybe like this.

```
this.state = {
    region:{this.getInitialState}
}
```

The error said you need an object, not a string, so you need to initialize the region using that method somehow

Comment: it gives me warning and also display nothing, `getInitialState was defined on app. a plain JavaScrpit class. This is only supported for classes created using react.creatclass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?`

Comment: Sorry, Ive never really used React. See if the edit helps

Answer (score -1):

if your using Genymotion you must install Google Services or try it in actual Android Device.